# unable to make parent tab active on click of child tab with bootstrap in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i am using bootstrap tab and this is my master page:

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                 <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Users <b class="caret"></b></a>//this is my 1st tab
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="">Staff</a>//this is my child tab
                                <li><a href="">Clients</a>//this is my child tab
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

 @Html.MenuItem("Categories", "categories", "Admin")//this is my second tab.
```

this is my html helper:

```
public static class MenuExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
            this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
            string text,
            string action,
            string controller
        )
        {
            var li = new TagBuilder("li");
            var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
            var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
            var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                li.AddCssClass("active");
            }
            li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
        }
    }



<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Users <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

now for above line how do i specify **classname data-toggle** property in below line:

```
@Html.MenuItem("Staff", "staff", "Admin")
```

can anybody tell me??

Comment: Which property "class" or "data-toggle" you want to set?

Comment: class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown".i want to set this class name and data-toggle property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please accept cssClass and DataToggle parameters in MenuItem helper method.
Like:

```
        public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
            this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
            string text,
            string action,
            string controller,
            string dataTogVal,
            string cssClass
        )
```

Next, call the 5 parameter overload of ActionLink method, and pass dataTogVal and cssClass. Like:

```
 li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller, null, new { @class = cssClass, data_toggle = dataTogVal }).ToHtmlString();
```